# Declaring global variables

Tags: python, global-variables

I have 2 question regarding global variables:

1. Why can't I declare a list as a global variable as so: `global list_ex = []`?
2. I have already defined a global variable that I am trying to use in a function, but can't:

   ```
   global column

   def fx_foo(cols):
       common = set(cols).intersection(set(column)) #Error Here!!
   ```

When I try to access column inside the function, I get an error:

> NameError: global name 'column' is not defined

Comment: You have to declare it *inside* of the function

Comment: What makes you think you can't make a list global?

Comment: You are misunderstanding the `global` keyword and what it does. Python does not have variable declarations like other languages, so what you are doing doesn't make sense in Python. In most languages, `global` means *make this visible everywhere*. In Python, `global` means *look for this in the global scope*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not using `global` correctly. You don't need to use it **at all**.

You need to actually *set* a global `column` variable, there is none right now. `global` does not make the variable available. Just create a global `column` first:

```
column = []
```

then refer to it in your function. That is what the `NameError` exception is trying to tell you; Python cannot find the global `column` variable, you didn't assign anything to the name so it doesn't exist.

You only need to use `global` if you want to *assign* to a global `column` *in your function*:

```
def somefunction():
    global column
    column = [1, 2, 3]
```

Here the `global` keyword is needed to distinguish `column` from a *local* variable in the function.

Compare:

```
>>> foo = 1
>>> def set_foo():
...     foo = 2
...
>>> set_foo()
>>> foo
1
```

to

```
>>> foo = 1
>>> def set_foo():
...     global foo
...     foo = 2
...
>>> set_foo()
>>> foo
2
```

The first form only set a local variable, the second form set the global variable instead.

Comment: For clarification, the *local* variable in the function would disappear (go out of scope) as soon as the function ended, but by declaring it as global, it does not disappear.

Comment: @Imagine: That is a different thing really, but yes.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword global means you are explicitly using a variable declared outside the scope of a function.

Your variable must be declared normally:

```
column = []
```

and declared global in the function that uses it

```
def fx_foo(cols):
    global column
    common = set(cols).intersection(set(column))
```

It is used to allow python to distinguish between new local variables and reused global variables.

Comment: As Martijn said in reply to Tom's post -- the global keyword not being used in the function is not the problem.

Comment: You do *not* need the `global column` line **at all**.

Comment: So unlike in C/C++, we need to declare the scope of the variable at the beginning of every function (so if there are 3 functions which use a global var, I need to type `global var` in each of the 3 functions explicitly).

Comment: @Max Kim -- Only if the functions need to modify the global var.

Comment: @Imagine so if I only need to access values from `var`, then I don't need to add `global`?

Comment: @MaxKim -- Correct, the global keyword is only necessary for changing var, not accessing it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : agreed. in this case there is no need as column is not assigned in the function. I think the actual issue is that Max Kim didn't assigned the column variable at all (not outside nor inside the function)

Answer (score 1):

this will work :

```
column =[]

def fx_foo(cols):
    global column
    common = set(cols).intersection(set(column))
```

but this will work even without `global` as `column` will be considered as nonlocal here

```
column =[]
def fx_foo(cols):
    common = set(cols).intersection(set(column))
```

I think It is more interesting to assign data to `column`  if You want to display `global` feature (as You can use column from nonlocals without global declaration if you don't assign anything to it)

```
column =[]
def fx_foo(cols):   
    global column     
    column = set(cols).intersection(set(column))
```

or

```
def fx_foo(cols): 
    column =[]          
    global column 
    column = set(cols).intersection(set(column))
```

Comment: Ignore my previous comment (if you noticed it before I deleted it): I confused `common` and `column`.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables need to be declared global inside of the function not on the outside. A variable declared outside a function is by default global.

Functions don't need to declare a variable as global if they only need to access it. The global declaration is just if you need to modify the global variable.

Therefore, in your case, I suggest that you look into what column actually is when you're passing it to the function, because I think the problem may have something to do with that.